# Share Proxy Connection to another PC

Tags: proxy, sharing

I really hope someone can help me fix this . let me explain

I have 2 Laptop the first laptop connect to internet via WiFi Directly from Modem . I have Socks 5 Software allowing me to choose any ip from any country on the first laptop runs on 127.0.0.1 Port 9951 + Proxifier Software to redirect all local software's / browsers to the socks 5 connection and everything working just great .

Now i want to share this Socks 5 connection to the second laptop using LAN Cable from the first laptop . the problem is Proxifier only redirect local software to use that Proxy . in the second laptop i get the real Modem IP instead of Socks 5 IP

What do i need to let the second laptop get the proxy connection without doing any configuration in the second laptop ? so that if i choose another Proxy IP from the first laptop that will fly all the way to second laptop

this is sound like easy task but from what i read in the internet it's almost like rocket science .

I'm open to use any software even if not free to fix this problem if its possible in the first place